# How to exclude resolved plugin in Gradle 5.x with a custom one?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

For Gradle 5.x,

Can a plugin that is resolved in a transitive dependency of a plugin be excluded (same way 'exclude' works in gradle for dependennt code libraries) and a custom plugin be supplied in place of that ?

I am able to supply my own custom plugin via following code :

```
    buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('/home/developer/Workspace/custom-gradle-plugin-0.3.6.jar')
    }
   }

apply plugin: com.custom.gradle.plugins.CustomSupportPlugin
```

But this is not able to override the plugin that is being resolved via transitive plugin resolution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8373) ,

I modified the build.gradle in following way to make it work (increased the version number of my plugin from that of published on the repository):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('/home/developer/Workspace/custom-gradle-plugin-0.3.7.jar')
    }
 configurations.classpath {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.custom:custom-gradle-plugin:0.3.7'
        }
    }
}
```

Result of command :

```
gradle buildEnvironment
```

Before:

```
classpath
 \--- com.custom:custom-gradle-plugin:0.3.6
```

After :

```
classpath
 \--- com.custom:custom-gradle-plugin:0.3.6 -> 0.3.7
```